# Listening to folder create, delete, renamed and mail flagged events in imap server?

Tags: node.js, email, imap

Using IMAP IDLE it is possible to listen for new mail and delete mail events. I used node-imap module in node.js to do that. But is it possible to listen for the flag change events like mark as read, unread and also folder creation/deletion/rename events?

I read about IMAP NOTIFY extension here they specified imap client  but it seems gmail is not supporting it and also in node.js I can't find anymodules that implemented this "IMAP NOTIFY". Please give any suggestion to achieve this.

Comment: A server may send flag change events while IDLE as an unsolicited FETCH response. It is not possible to get folder change events in baseline IMAP.

Comment: @Max With Imap NOTIFY extension we can get folder change events but it is rarely supported among imap servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the flag and keyword changes, yes, the `IDLE` extension was designed just for this purpose. Please note that [Gmail does not report flag changes when in IDLE](http://marc.info/?l=imap&m=139056685827240&w=2). The linked thread contains a workaround. Gmail's behaivor is completely breaindead, of course.

As for other changes, [the NOTIFY extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5465#section-5.4) is what you are looking for, but its support among servers is rather scarce -- only Dovecot, AFAIK. If your favorite IMAP client library doesn't offer it already, you should ask their authors.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Yes NOTIFY extension is rarely supported among imap servers.. And I found another useful command CONDSTORE that would solve my problem in imap syncing..