# How can I use CONDSTORE in dovecot

Tags: imap, dovecot

I'm devoloping a webmail! 
There is a problem.When dovecot receives a new mail how can I trigger my customer program.
I have found the notify plugin of dovecot in url 'http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins' However it does not tell me how to use that
I also find the same problem in url  [Listening to folder create, delete, renamed and mail flagged events in imap server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981316/) 
it tells that use CONDSTORE. 
But how to use CONDSTORE command !

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the information you need to know about CONDSTORE here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4551